# Detect blocked popup while using noopener flag?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm opening a popup with `window.open('https://example.org', 'hello', 'noopener')`, this function always returns `null`.

Looking online, the only way to detect if a `window.open` was blocked is to check for the return value of `window.open`:

```
const wasNOTblocked = window.open('https://example.org', 'hello')?.closed !== 'undefined';
```

But the problem is that this system can't work while `noopener` is set, as `window.open` will not return the window object when it's set.

How can I detect if my popup was blocked?
It would be acceptable a solution that makes use of the Web Extensions API (MV3) in case.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found is to use BroadcastChannel to ping other windows and check if any of them is the one that was just open. It only works if the popup window content is controlled by me and it's on the same domain but that's okay for my use case.

```
const tabPresenceBroadcastChannel = new BroadcastChannel('tab-presence');

export const checkTabPresence = (url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => resolve(false), 1000);
    const callback = async (event) => {
      // If we don't receive a response in time we assume the popup blocker blocked the tab

      let available = false;

      while (available === false) {
        if (event.type === 'response' && event.url === url) {
          available = true;
        } else {
          await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
        }
      }

      // If we receive a response we cancel the above timer and resolve the promise positively
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      resolve(available);

      tabPresenceBroadcastChannel.removeEventListener('message', callback);
    };

    tabPresenceBroadcastChannel.addEventListener('message', callback);
    tabPresenceBroadcastChannel.postMessage({ type: 'request', url });
  });
};

tabPresenceBroadcastChannel.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.type === 'request' && event.url === window.location.origin) {
    tabPresenceBroadcastChannel.postMessage({
      type: 'response',
      url: event.url,
    });
  }
});
```

Usage

```
const didOpenPopup = await checkTabPresence('https://example.org');
```